# list.map is not a function help create-react-app

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app

Hi could someone tell me why I am getting the list.map is not a function error? I am pretty sure my React code makes list an array but I am a beginner so I may have overlooked something

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Task from "./Task";

function Home() {  
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [task, setTask] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setList(list.push(task));
  }, [task]);

  const addTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTask(text);
    setText("");
  };

  const updateText = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <h3>Home Page</h3>
      <form onSubmit={addTask}>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={updateText} />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      <div className="listoftasks">
        {list.map((t) => (
          <Task
            text={t}            
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.push()` does not return the updated array. Therefore you should use `Array.concat()` -

```
useEffect(() => {
    setList(list.concat(task));
  }, [task]);
```

Comment: But my consideration is why map is not a function since it has [] initially defined?

Comment: map is not a function defined on Number. And you are populating the list with a number now.

Comment: because it's not a function for list. As he is setting the list to a number.
setList(list.push(task)); => setList(Array Length)

Comment: ha... i didnt know `push` actually returned the new length :-)

Answer (score 4):

Or use spread operator, for immutability functional approach:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      setList([...list, task]);
  }, [task]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When `task` is updating you're setting the new value of `list` to the result of `push` which is the new length of the array.

You should push and then update the state

```
  useEffect(() => {
    list.push(task);
    setList(list.slice());
  }, [task]);
```

Comment: nope, you need to create a new array reference for the state to update correctly, you are pushing to an existing array

Answer (score 0):

`Array.push()` returns a number, the new length of the now modified in place array.

```js
useEffect(() => setList(list.push(newThing))) // list is now a number!!!
```

You've turned list into a number, so now for a 3 item array(that once was 2 items) you'll be calling `3.map()` and a `3` doesn't have a map method on it.

Worse yet if you just push and reset the reference you'll not update

```js
useEffect(() => {
  list.push(newThing)
  setList(list) // won't update! list === list is true, and thus does not trigger render
})
```

You can go about updating the list a few ways by making new array and passing it with concatenation

```js
useEffect(() => setList(list.concat(newThing)) // works
```

or spreading

```js
useEffect(() => setList([...list, newThing])) // works
```

Once this is done, it will fail the check to see if the passed entity is the same value. This should allow the render to be triggered and your new updates to appear.